# MYSQL optimization questions about values on server

Tags: mysql

I have an etc/my.cnf file with these values:

```
innodb_force_recovery=6
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
innodb_strict_mode=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
performance-schema=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
thread_concurrency=4
max_connections=250
max_user_connections=30
key_buffer_size=256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
join_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=1M
interactive_timeout=45
wait_timeout=360
connect_timeout=120
max_allowed_packet=1053741824
max_connect_errors=10
query_cache_limit=20M
query_cache_type=1
flush
flush_time=60
open_files_limit=50000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

What would you recommend when having this kind of warnings in Mysql please:

```
created tmp disk tables    345.7K
handler read rnd 165M
handler read rnd next 45G
innodb buffer pool reads 140k
opened tables 2k
Qcache lowmenprunes 50k
sort merge passes : 55
select full join 450k
```

All the above showing as "High" in PHPMYADMIN

The site is relatively slow and I wonder if increasing the memory in some cases might help a bit but I would like to have an opinion on this please first.

Thank you.

Comment: Need to divide those by `Uptime` to get "per second".  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, `SHOW VARIABLES`, and how much RAM you have.

Answer (score 1):

**On settings:**

`innodb_force_recovery` - don't set this. Its dangerous to have this as default.

`query_cache_limit=20M`
`query_cache_type=1`
Disable these. They are a concurrency problem.

`flush` `flush_time=60` - I've never seen these set. Sounds like a workaround for MyISAM being default.

`default-storage-engine=MyISAM` don't set MyISAM being a default. It has horrible concurrency problems. Change existing tables to innodb.

**On status variables warnings:**

- `created tmp disk tables    345.7K`
- `handler read rnd 165M`
- `handler read rnd next 45G`
- `select full join 450k`
  All these indicate poorly indexed queries. Enable your [slow query log](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) and start asking questions on [how to index your tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing) better.
- `innodb buffer pool reads 140k`

Your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` isn't big enough. Especially after you change all your tables to InnoDB. Start at several G and increase until the `innodb_buffer_pool_reads` is significantly (<<1%) less than `innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests`.

- `opened tables 2k`

Might not be that bad. Check the number of active tables and if > 2k increase [table_open_cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache).

- `Qcache lowmenprunes   50k`

Won't matter when query cache is disabled.

- `sort merge passes : 55`

When indexing is improved maybe this won't be needed.  If you do a lot of large table sorts maybe [sort_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) should be increased, but with correct indexing there is often no need to sort results.